How to Vertically Stack Multiple Plots with Custom Color Functions and Opacity in Mathematica?
I have 4 plots, k1, k2, k3, and k4, that are generated using the code below. They currently look like this:

I would like to stack them vertically, similar to how it is shown in this example from another Stack Exchange post:

I am not sure how to adapt their approach to stack my specific plots. Below is the code I use to generate k1, k2, k3, and k4. Can someone please suggest how to vertically stack these plots while preserving their individual styles?
eval1a[x_] := -((60 - 44 Cos[x] + 20 Cos[2 x] - 4 Cos[3 x] + 
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
        2154 - 2896 Cos[x] + 1915 Cos[2 x] - 888 Cos[3 x] + 
         278 Cos[4 x] - 56 Cos[5 x] + 5 Cos[6 x]])/(8 (15 Cos[x] - 
         6 (3 + Cos[2 x]) + Cos[3 x])));

eval2a[x_] := -((2 Sin[x/2]^2 Sin[x]^2)/(
   15 Cos[x] - 6 (3 + Cos[2 x]) + Cos[3 x]));

eval3a[x_] = (-60 + 44 Cos[x] - 20 Cos[2 x] + 4 Cos[3 x] + 
     Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
       2154 - 2896 Cos[x] + 1915 Cos[2 x] - 888 Cos[3 x] + 
        278 Cos[4 x] - 56 Cos[5 x] + 5 Cos[6 x]])/(8 (15 Cos[x] - 
       6 (3 + Cos[2 x]) + Cos[3 x]));

eval4a[x_] := -((
   8 Sin[x/2]^6)/(-18 + 15 Cos[x] - 6 Cos[2 x] + Cos[3 x]));

max1 = 1;
max2 = FindMaximum[eval2a[x Degree], {x, 90}][[1]];
max3 = FindMaximum[eval3a[x Degree], {x, 90}][[1]];
max4 = FindMaximum[eval4a[x Degree], {x, 180}][[1]];

normEval1a[x_] = eval1a[x Degree]/max1;
normEval2a[x_] = eval2a[x Degree]/max2;
normEval3a[x_] = eval3a[x Degree]/max3;
normEval4a[x_] = eval4a[x Degree]/max4;

rangemin = 0;
rangemax = 1;
k1 = Plot[Cos[x Degree]^2, {x, 0, 180}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, {Opacity[normEval1a[x]], 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][eval1a[x Degree]]}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {rangemin, rangemax}}, Exclusions -> None, 
   Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, {0, -0.02}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}], Automatic}, 
   Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 400];

k2 = Plot[Sin[x Degree]^2, {x, 0, 180}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, {Opacity[normEval2a[x]], 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][eval2a[x Degree]]}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {rangemin, rangemax}}, Exclusions -> None, 
   Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, {0, -0.02}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}], Automatic}, 
   Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 400];

k3 = Plot[Sin[2 x Degree]^2, {x, 0, 180}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, {Opacity[normEval3a[x]], 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][eval3a[x Degree]]}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {rangemin, rangemax}}, Exclusions -> None, 
   Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, {0, -0.02}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}], Automatic}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][eval3a[x]]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Background -> Black, 
   ImageSize -> 400];

k4 = Plot[Cos[2 x Degree]^2, {x, 0, 180}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, {Opacity[normEval4a[x]], 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][eval4a[x Degree]]}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {rangemin, rangemax}}, Exclusions -> None, 
   Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, {0, -0.02}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}], Automatic}, 
   Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 400];

{k1, k2, k3, k4}

The reason why I want to stack them this way is because the actual equations I’m plotting overlap, making it difficult to distinguish where one ends and another begins. For your convenience, I’ve included the actual figures below.
As you can see, there are dashed curves on top of solid curves. The dashed curves and some of the solid curves do not span the entire x range, but in this format it's hard to tell where they begin and end. For this reason, to improve clarity, I thought separating them in 3D space might make the visualization easier to follow.
ACTUAL FIGURES I WANT TO PLOT

UPDATE
Using one of the solutions provided below, it is possible to add planes at the location of each graph and adjust the line thickness accordingly. However, when rotating the graphics, the plot lines no longer stay aligned with the planes, which becomes especially noticeable when the line thickness is increased. Additionally, I would like to place text on each plane, but I encounter a similar issue: the text does not remain fixed to the plane during rotation.
Any suggestions or solutions to address these problems would be greatly appreciated.
{}
lineThickness = 0.03;

Show[
 Show[
  MapThread[
   ParametricPlot3D[{x, #1, #2},
     {x, 0, 180},
     ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y}, {Opacity[#3[x]], 
        ColorData["Rainbow"][#4[x Degree]]}],
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     PlotStyle -> {#5, Thickness[#6]},
     WorkingPrecision -> 20,
     PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {rangemin, rangemax}},
     Exclusions -> None,
     Ticks -> {Table[{i, i, {0, -0.02}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}], Automatic},
     Background -> Black,
     ImageSize -> 400] &, {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {Cos[x Degree]^2, 
     Sin[x Degree]^2, Sin[2 x Degree]^2, 
     Cos[2 x Degree]^2}, {normEval1a, normEval2a, normEval3a, 
     normEval4a}, {eval1a, eval2a, eval3a, eval4a}, {Automatic, 
     Automatic, Dashed, Dashed}, {lineThickness, lineThickness, 
     lineThickness, lineThickness}}], PlotRange -> All, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
 Graphics3D[
  {
   {Opacity[0.2], LightBlue, 
    InfinitePlane[{{10, 0, -10}, {170, 0, -10}, {170, 0, 10}}], 
    Text[Style["Plane at y = 0", White, 18], {90, 0, 
      0}]},(*Plane at y=0*)
   {Opacity[0.3], LightBlue, 
    InfinitePlane[{{10, 1, -10}, {170, 1, -10}, {170, 1, 
       10}}]},(*Plane at y=1*)
   {Opacity[0.4], LightBlue, 
    InfinitePlane[{{10, 2, -10}, {170, 2, -10}, {170, 2, 
       10}}]},(*Plane at y=2*)
   {Opacity[0.5], LightBlue, 
    InfinitePlane[{{10, 3, -10}, {170, 3, -10}, {170, 3, 
       10}}]}  (*Plane at y=3*)
   }
  ]
 ]


Thank you so very much, @Syed! You made someone very happy. :) You are a legend!

I'm looking at doing that right now! Cheers, @Syed

Is there some reason you don't want to plot all 4 on a single 2-D plot?  Generally, things are hard to compare (such as where the peaks and valleys are among the plots) on a 3D plot.

@jimB I tried that approach, but the equations I’m plotting overlap, making it difficult to distinguish where one ends and another begins. For your convenience, I’ve included the actual equations, formatted as you suggested, in the question section. For this reason, to improve clarity, I thought separating them in 3D space might make the visualization easier to follow.

I'm at strong believer in animated, color 3D spinning graphics but mainly to wake up an audience.  If one needs to compare shapes, then a simpler figure is simply better.  The overlap you mention is made worse by your current color/transparency choices.

If you use a White background all 4 curves are easily distinguishable using Show[{k1, k2, k3, k4}].

@JimB I appreciate the advice. The plots will have to be on white background eventually. That is not my concern at the moment. I agree that I can do better with color choices and line thickness too. I want to explore other possibilities on how to present these plots that conserves page space provided it does not complicate the interpretation of the plots.

Keeping all your definitions,
Show[
 MapThread[
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, #1, #2}, {x, 0, 180}
    , ColorFunction -> Function[
      {x, y}, {Opacity[#3[x]]
       , ColorData["Rainbow"][#4[x Degree]]}
      ]
    , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
    , PlotStyle -> #5
    , WorkingPrecision -> 20
    , PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {rangemin, rangemax}}
    , Exclusions -> None
    , Ticks -> {
      Table[{i, i, {0, -0.02}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}]
      , Automatic
      }
    , Background -> Black
    , ImageSize -> 400
    ] &,
  {
   {0, 1, 2, 3}
   , {Cos[x Degree]^2, Sin[x Degree]^2
    , Sin[2 x Degree]^2, Cos[2 x Degree]^2}
   , {normEval1a, normEval2a, normEval3a, normEval4a}
   , {eval1a, eval2a, eval3a, eval4a}
   , {Automatic, Automatic, Dashed, Dashed}
   }
  ]
 , PlotRange -> All
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]




$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Index your variables to facilitate their use.
evala[1, x_] := -((60 - 44 Cos[x] + 20 Cos[2 x] - 4 Cos[3 x] +
       Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
         2154 - 2896 Cos[x] + 1915 Cos[2 x] - 888 Cos[3 x] + 
          278 Cos[4 x] - 56 Cos[5 x] + 5 Cos[6 x]])/
     (8 (15 Cos[x] - 6 (3 + Cos[2 x]) + Cos[3 x])));

evala[2, x_] := -((2 Sin[x/2]^2 Sin[x]^2)/
     (15 Cos[x] - 6 (3 + Cos[2 x]) + Cos[3 x]));

evala[3, x_] = (-60 + 44 Cos[x] - 20 Cos[2 x] + 4 Cos[3 x] +
     Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
       2154 - 2896 Cos[x] + 1915 Cos[2 x] - 888 Cos[3 x] + 
        278 Cos[4 x] - 56 Cos[5 x] + 5 Cos[6 x]])/
   (8 (15 Cos[x] - 6 (3 + Cos[2 x]) + Cos[3 x]));

evala[4, x_] := 
   -((8 Sin[x/2]^6)/(-18 + 15 Cos[x] - 6 Cos[2 x] + Cos[3 x]));

With the indexed variables:
max[n_] := max[n] = MaxValue[evala[n, x Degree], x] //
     FullSimplify // Quiet;

normEvala[n_, x_] := normEvala[n, x Degree] =
   evala[n, x Degree]/max[n];

funcs = {Cos[x Degree], Sin[x Degree], Sin[2 x Degree], 
    Cos[2 x Degree]}^2;

rangemin = 0;
rangemax = 1;

plot[n_] := plot[n] = Module[{plt},
   plt = Plot[funcs[[n]], {x, 0, 180}];
   ListLinePlot3D[
    Cases[plt, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]] /.
     {x_, y_} :> {x, n, y},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
      Opacity[normEvala[n, x],
       ColorData["Rainbow"][evala[n, x Degree]]]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False]]

Combining the plots,
Show[plot /@ Range[4],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {0, 5}, {rangemin, rangemax}}]



Thank you so much, @Bob Hanlon! The code looks great. Unfortunately, I’m unable to use it directly as I’m working with version 12.1, which doesn’t support ListLinePlot3D. I'm currently working with ChatGPT to see if I can modify the code to be compatible with 12.1, as I’d like to make use of your solution. Many thanks. :)

@QuantumKid Use Plot[funcs[[n]], {x, 0, 180}, PlotPoints -> 3000] and ListPointPlot3D instead of ListLinePlot3D.

Thank you @E.Chan-López! That worked a treat. :)
